# Dygraphs - error - CSV is out of order; order it correctly to speed loading

Tags: dygraphs

I get a graph generated from an external txt file that is properly rendered, but get this error in console.

CSV is out of order; order it correctly to speed loading.

Think this is slowing down the rendering.
Cannot find any information on how to fix correct the CSV.
Txt file is correct csv format, or graph would be wrong.

Using dygraph script from cdnjs - 1.1.1

Has anyone any experience of this or ideas on a fix?

Search the dygraphs web site but could not find any information on this error.
Blog last entry 2014!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The CSV file should be constructed such that the x-axis values are in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for the  reply, checked my data file and it is asc date/time order?
eg 2022-12-31 09:00:00,0.177,0.385,1.38 / 2022-12-31 09:15:00,0.177,0.386,1.38 /  2022-12-31 09:30:00,0.177,0.386,1.38

Comment: @RayRich The three values you show are correctly ordered, but there are some misordered ones in your dataset. Is your datestamp based on local time? If so, then DST changes will cause time to “jump back”. It’s best to use UTC timestamps.